# Is it possible to protect the structure of an Excel sheet without protecting the contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

We want to protect the structure of an Excel sheet (the user should not add or remove columns or change the format of the cells) but allowing him to change cell content and adding or removing rows.

Is that possible? When I click protect sheet I cannot click Ok unless I select "protect the content of the sheet".

Comment: There are several options for protection: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/protect-a-worksheet-3179efdb-1285-4d49-a9c3-f4ca36276de6 . Have you checked them?

Comment: *When I click protect workbook* Protect single worksheet, not whole workbook

Comment: @Akina, sorry, fixed the typos.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**How it Works:**

1. Click Review Tab.
2. Find & Click **Protect Sheet.**
3. Finally un-check **Format Cell, Columns & 
   Rows.**
4. Also, un-check **Insert & Delete Columns.**

Answer (score 1):

You may use the global option of "Protect worksheet and contents of locked cells", because the checkboxes below will limit the protection to the checked items.

Uncheck the global option to disable all the protections when you yourself are updating
the worksheet.